# Initializing parent's const members in child class

Tags: c++, oop, initialization

I am not even sure this is possible, so I'd like a clarification. I have a parent class with const array of strings and I would like it to be initialized by its child classes, such as:

```
class CParent{
  CParent();
  const char** strings;
};
```

and child class

```
class CChild:CParent{
  CChild();
};

CChild::CChild()
: CParent::strings{
  "First",
  "Second"
}
{
  CParent();
  // some code
}
```

I need this because I will be calling CParent's constructor and there I need to use the strings. It can be done by passing it through argument, but I was wondering if something like this was possible.

---

**Edit:** I forgot to write a few things when rewriting my code here, so I will rather copy-paste it so I don't forget anything now. I rewrote it using strings and vectors using Andy Prowl's help:

```
class CMenu {
public:
    CMenu(std::vector<std::string> const& s);
protected:
    std::vector<std::string> choicesStr;
};

CMenu::CMenu(std::vector<std::string> const & s) : choicesStr(s) {
    // code code
}

class CGameTypeMenu : public CMenu {
public:
    CGameTypeMenu();
};

CGameTypeMenu::CGameTypeMenu() 
 :CMenu(std::vector<std::string>("aaa","bbb")){ // This is where I 
                                                   get some nasty errors

}
```

The error looks like this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:63:0,
                 from CMenu.h:13,
                 from CGameTypeMenu.h:11,
                 from CGameTypeMenu.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_string<char>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
(5+ more similar lines follow)
```

Comment: That's not a const array. It's a non-const array of const strings.

Comment: `CMenu(std::vector<std::string>("aaa","bbb")){ // This is where I get some nasty errors` - because you can't do that without C++11 either. See my answer.

Comment: I thought you meant that I can't do the `CParent({"foo"})` version. Ok then

Comment: But in that case, I don't know how to call the constructor, when I have to declare the vector first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the constructor of `CChild` call the constructor of `CParent` and pass your array as its argument. You might then actually end up trying to do something like this:

```
CChild() : CParent({ "First", "Second" }) { }
```

which is called *brace initialization* and it is is possible only with C++11 support. In case you need C++03 solution and you want to keep using `const char*` for storing strings, then :

```
class CParent {
public:
    CParent(const char* s[]) : strings(s) { }
    const char** strings;
};

class CChild : public CParent {
public:
    CChild() : CParent(strings_) { }
private:
    static const char* strings_[];
};

const char* CChild::strings_[] = { "First", "Second" };
```

just note that since `strings_` is an array, this `const` member must be initialized in source file.

Although I recommend you to use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays and `std::string` instead of C-style strings. In that case this code could look like this:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;

class CParent {
public:
    CParent(const std::vector<std::string>& s) : strings(s) { }
    const StringVector strings;
};

class CChild : public CParent {
public:
    CChild()
    : CParent(strings_) { }
private:
    static const std::string s_[];
    static const StringVector strings_;
};

const std::string CChild::s_[] = { "First", "Second" };
const StringVector CChild::strings_ =
  StringVector(CChild::s_, CChild::s_ + sizeof(CChild::s_)/sizeof(std::string));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains it well

Answer (score 5):

Just do it the right way (this solution works for C++11 only):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class CParent
{
    protected:
//  ^^^^^^^^^^ Make sure your constructor is at least protected,
//             or it will be inaccessible to derived classes

    CParent(std::vector<std::string> const& s) : strings(s) { };

    std::vector<std::string> strings;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use containers and classes from the C++ Standard
//                           Library rather than raw pointers
};

class CChild : public CParent
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I suppose you forgot this.
//                            Inheritance is private by
//                            default, which does not seem
//                            to be what you want   
{
    CChild();
};

CChild::CChild()
    :
    CParent({"First", "Second"}) // C++11 ONLY!
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//          Implicit construction of the vector of string
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `CParent({"First", "Second"})` is possible only with C++11 support.

Comment: Thanks, I was using const char* because I didn't know ncurses worked with strings; good to know. I changed the code according to your post, but I am getting errors when calling parent's constructor in initialization of the child. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @MartinMelka: Sorry, I made a wrong assumption when writing code for C++03. This solution works for C++11 only.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to initialize const members of the base class is to pass the initializing arguments to a constructor of the base class in the initialization list of the derived class constructor, and the base constructor take this arguments to initialize the const member in his initialization list.

“Inside” any constructor (pass the initialization list) any member (derived or base) is already (default is not explicit) constructed, and const cannot be change anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to member initialize `CParent` members is through an appropriate `CParent` constructor.

As a workaround, you can initialize parent members through *assignment* in the child's constructor, if the parent members are accessible, i.e. `protected` or `public`.

This workaround is of course not possible, if the members were truly `const`, i.e.

```
const char ** const strings;
```

But the correct way is to keep the parent members private and provide a proper parent constructor.